# CalendarViewDayItem event not firing

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, calendarview

I'm trying to add a `RightTapped` event to each `CalendarViewDayItem`. `DoubleTapped` event works fine, but `RightTapped` is not raised despite of that it's created.

This is how I have created them:

```
private void calviewSun_CalendarViewDayItemChanging(CalendarView sender, CalendarViewDayItemChangingEventArgs args)
{
    
    args.Item.DoubleTapped += CalendarViewDayItem_DoubleTapped;
    args.Item.RightTapped  += CalendarViewDayItem_RightTapped;   
}
```

I have tried setting breakpoints to check if they were raised but they had any other problems, but they are never raised. I have check that `args.Item.IsRightTapEnbaled` is set to true.

I don't know why is not raising the event.

Comment: Could you please tell me why you want to handle the right tapped event?

Comment: To show some options related to the date, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use [UIElement.AddHandler() Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.addhandler?view=winrt-22000) to add right tapped event for the `CalendarViewDayItem`.

The code looks like this:

```
 private void CalendarView_CalendarViewDayItemChanging(CalendarView sender, CalendarViewDayItemChangingEventArgs args)
    {
        args.Item.IsRightTapEnabled = true;
        args.Item.DoubleTapped += Item_DoubleTapped; 
       // args.Item.RightTapped += Item_RightTapped;

        args.Item.AddHandler(UIElement.RightTappedEvent, new RightTappedEventHandler(Item_RightTapped), true);
    }

    private void Item_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("RightTapped");
    }
```